# Контекст некорректно создает экземпляр сущности, используя метод Set<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, di, ef-core-3.1

Использовал [данную архитектуру](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implementing-onion-architecture-in-asp-net-core-3-om/) для создания своего приложения. Приложение представляет собой простой телеграм бот, который общается с локальным хостом. Сущности из бд, которые используются в бд работают корректно за исключением одной.
При её деплое в репозиторий возникает исключение:[image]

Как уже говорил ранее, с другими сущностями проблем не возникало и операции с бд работали корректно.
Код, где задействован данный функционал прикрепляю ниже:

Контекст данных

```
 public class StoreContext:DbContext
{
    public StoreContext(DbContextOptions<StoreContext> options):base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        new ProductBuilder(modelBuilder.Entity<Product>());
        new CustomerBuilder(modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>());
        new OrderBuilder(modelBuilder.Entity<Order>());
        new FileOnlineBuilderBuilder(modelBuilder.Entity<FileOnline>());
    }
}
```

Сервис, сохраняющий новый файл

```
 public class FileService : IFileService
{
    private IFileRepository _repository;
    private ILogger<FileOnline> _logger;
    private StoreContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public FileService(IFileRepository repository, StoreContext context, IMapper mapper, ILogger<FileOnline> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _repository = repository;
        _context = context;
    }
    public IEnumerable<string> GetFilesId()
    {
        var collectionId = _repository.GetAll();
        return collectionId.Select(_mapper.Map<FileDTO>).Select(f=>f.FileId);
    }

    public void SetFileId(FileDTO file)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileId))
        {
            _repository.Add(_mapper.Map<FileOnline>(file));
             _context.SaveChanges();
            _logger.LogInformation("File id was succesfully stored");
            return;
        }
        _logger.LogError("It was handled exception while receiving a file id");
    }
}
```

Интерфейс для базового класса репозитория

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T: BaseEntity
{
    T Get(Guid id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    void Add(T entity);
    T Update(T updatetEntity);
    bool Delete(T removedEntity);
    
}
```

Базовый класс репозитория

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T:BaseEntity
{
    protected readonly DbSet<T> _entity;
    public Repository(StoreContext context)
    {
        _entity = context.Set<T>();
    }
    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        if (entity != null)
        {
            if (_entity.Contains(entity))
                return;
            _entity.Add(entity);
        }
    }

    public bool Delete(T removedEntity)
    {
        if (removedEntity != null)
        {
            _entity.Remove(removedEntity);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public T Get(Guid id)
    {
        return _entity.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll() => _entity.AsEnumerable();

    public T Update(T updatetEntity)
    {
        if (updatetEntity != null)
        {
            var returnedEntity = _entity.Update(updatetEntity).Entity;
            return returnedEntity;
        }
        return updatetEntity;
    }
}
```

Сам репозиторий

```
 public class FileRepository : Repository<FileOnline>, IFileRepository
{
    public FileRepository(StoreContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

}
```

IFileRepository просто наследуется от IRepository<*сущность*>

Конфигурация DependencyInversion:

```
 services.AddDbContext<StoreContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString"])
            .UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.Create(config => config.AddConsole()));

        });
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
        services.AddTelegramBot(Configuration);
        services.AddTransient<ICommandTelegramService, CommandTelegramService>();
        services.AddTransient<IFileService, FileService>();
        services.AddTransient<IOrderService, OrderService>();
        services.AddTransient<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
        services.AddTransient<ITelegramBotService, TelegramBotService>();
        services.AddScoped<IFileRepository, FileRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
```

Все сервисы- `Transient`, Репозитории- `Scoped`

FileDTO:

```
public class FileDTO
{
    public string FileId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

FileOnline

```
[Table("Files")]
public class FileOnline : BaseEntity
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string FileId { get; set; }
}
```

FileBuilder

```
public FileOnlineBuilderBuilder(EntityTypeBuilder<FileOnline> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(f => f.Id);
        builder.Property(f => f.FileId);
        builder.Property(f => f.Description);
    }
```

Comment: Выглядит на первый взгляд нормально. А покажите пожалуйста FileDTO, FileOnline и FileOnlineBuilderBuilder

Comment: Судя по ошибке, ваш контекст уже закрыт, а вы пытаетесь к нему обратиться. Добавьте поле контекста в репозиторий и сохраняйте его на протяжении всей жизни репозитория.

Comment: также вопрос, как так получается, что у вас `IFileService` - `Transient`, а `IFileRepository` - `Scoped`? У них разное время жизни? Если вам надо иметь репозиторий scoped, то вам надо что то типа [такого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50757900/312041) - то есть резолвить репозиторий когда он нужен.

Comment: У вас в комментах уже есть и подсказки, и вопросы и ссылки. Дерзайте.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо Вам большое! Все отлично заработало благодаря Вашей ссылке. Я могу отметить Ваш комментарий как ответ?

Comment: Комментарий нет, но вы можете перевести мой ответ с англ сюда или написать свой ответ.

Comment: [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50756984/asp-net-core-using-service-instance-to-call-method-in-another-method-which-runs/50757900#50757900) найдете ответ на заданный мною вопрос.